# multiple replace and adding preceding 0 if number is single digit

Tags: php

I have strings like following

```
Season 6, Episode 10
Season 21, Episode 10
Season 6, Episode 1
```

which should be converted to following string

```
S06E10
S21E10
S06E01
```

I tried below code

```
$shortseason = str_replace("Season ","S",$season);
$shortseason = str_replace("Episode ","E",$shortseason);
$shortseason = str_replace(", ","",$shortseason);
```

I cannot add preceding 0 in above code , Is there any other way to do it easily.

Comment: you need to use `sprintf("%02d", $num)`

Comment: @FrayneKonok : the problem is getting the number seperately from string

Comment: okey let me do it for you.

Comment: Check my answer. If you need to do the same for all then use simply the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use preg_replace to do this:

```
function convert($s) {
    return preg_replace ( '/^Season (\d+), Episode (\d+)$/e', "'S'.str_pad($1,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'E'.str_pad($2,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)", $s );
}

echo convert ( "Season 6, Episode 10" ) . "\n";
echo convert ( "Season 21, Episode 10" ) . "\n";
echo convert ( "Season 6, Episode 1" ) . "\n";
```

output:

```
S06E10
S21E10
S06E01
```

Comment: It is not adding preceding 0

Comment: @Vishnu it adds via str_pad

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression [and `preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
<?php

//Regular expression
$re = "/season\s(\d{1,2})\,\sepisode\s(\d{1,2})/i"; 

//Input string(s)
$str = "Season 6, Episode 10",
       "Season 21, Episode 10",
       "Season 6, Episode 1";

//Find matches
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

//Iterate through matches
for($n = 0; $n <= count($matches[0]) - 1; $n++){
    $s = sprintf("%02d", $matches[1][$n]);
    $e = sprintf("%02d", $matches[2][$n]);
    echo "S{$s}E{$e}";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

This will output:

> S06E10
>   S21E10
>   S06E01

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex *(after those `str_replace()`)* to add a `0` before that number if it is one-digit. Try this:

```
$season="Season 6, Episode 10
Season 21, Episode 10
Season 6, Episode 1";

$shortseason = str_replace("Season ","S",$season);
$shortseason = str_replace("Episode ","E",$shortseason);
$shortseason = str_replace(", ","",$shortseason);

$pattern1 = '/(S)(\dE)/m';
$pattern2 = '/(E)(\d)(?:\n|$)/m';
$replacement = '${1}0$2';
$shortseason = preg_replace($pattern1, $replacement, $shortseason );
echo preg_replace($pattern2, $replacement, $shortseason );
```

#### [PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZbekA)

Comment: working now thank you , but it is not adding preceding 0 for Season

Comment: sorry , lots of bug , Season 1, Episode 1 must be S01E01 , lashane answer is working , thanks anyways

Comment: @Vishnu Hooof ... I edited my answer and it works as well now *(after 5 try `;-)`)* .. btw I'm glad you find a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is it: try and let me know.

```
$str = "Season 6, Episode 10";

$arr = explode(", ", $str);

$shortseason1 = explode(" ", $arr[0]);
$shortseason2 = explode(" ", $arr[1]);

echo $short = substr($shortseason1[0], 0, 1).sprintf("%02d", $shortseason1[1]).substr($shortseason2[0], 0, 1).sprintf("%02d", $shortseason2[1]);
```

> Output: S06E10

Do the same for other.